# What has happened to Chantinelle "Ellie" after she got imprisoned by First of the Fallen?

Tags: vertigo-comics, hellblazer

I've been reading "John Constantine: Hellblazer" bit erratically and it seems that I'm missing some information about succubus Ellie that even the [Wiki](http://hellblazer.wikia.com/wiki/Ellie) doesn't provide:

Constantine and Ellie had quite good relationship: John helped to deliver her baby and later helped her to hide from the First of the Fallen by etching a sigil in her soul. She was the one that back-stabbed the Devil and made him mortal, although she had to go into hiding (while still partially protected) when he came back.

Then John makes a di#$ish move and seduces Ellie (oh irony) to gain more power and reduces her protection to last only as long as he lives, in revenge Ellie manipulates his friends and girlfriend to abandon Constantine. Getting desperate, John makes deal with FotF, sells Ellie away and the last we can see her she is tied down in hell and her mother, First's lover, promises to bring her through most horrible tortures imaginable.

What has happened later? Wiki suggest that she teamed up with Constantine again, but the whole episode of being punished for attempted coup is strangely omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Since I haven't seen any answers, the only information that I've managed to dig up comes from Wikipedia:

> While in Hell, John and Nergal met the demon Constantine, who tried to kill the original one. John was forced to let Nergal enter his body in order to finish him. Later they also encountered **Ellie, who seemed to have quite pardoned John for him selling her out to the First. She was not subject to any torture or punishment, either**.